# How to sort a java map with a custom comparator on values instead of keys

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap, key-value

How can we order the content of a map by comparing its values instead of the value of its keys? For example, how can we implement a method `sortByAbsoluteValue` that orders the map entries from the one with highest absolute value to lowest absolute value:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hashmap=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    hashmap.put("product5",100);
    hashmap.put("product6",-20);
    hashmap.put("product3",10);
    hashmap.put("product4",5);
    hashmap.put("product1",15);
    hashmap.put("product2",-40);
    hashmap.put("product9",0);
    hashmap.put("product7",70);
    hashmap.put("product8",30);
Map<String, Integer> map = sortByAbsoluteValue(hashmap);
```

Where `map.toString()` would output

```
{product5=100, product7=70, product2=-40, product8=30, product6=-20, product1=15, product3=10, product4=5, product9=0}
```

Comment: Share what did you try so far. It's unclear from the title and examples what do you need to achieve. HashMap is unsorted by its nature.

Comment: Are you trying to *print* the output in some form?  Or else, what manner of output are you expecting?  Because, generally speaking, you cannot modify the iteration order of an existing `Map`.

Comment: A `Map` is not a useful output from a sort method.  A `List` or `Set` would maintain the sort order.,

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc a `Set` will not maintain order more or less than a `Map`, in fact their implementations are very similar. There are many real-life situations where a `SortedMap` or `LinkedHashMap` are useful and good reasons they made it to `java.lang`

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with some of the comments hinting that a list is better suited when looking for sorted results, Java does allow some maps like the `TreeMap` to be sorted using `Comparator<>` functions.

Unfortunately, `Maps` are always sorted by key, but luckily, Java also provides `LinkedHashMap` which maintain their insertion order.

So the trick here is to first sort using the `Comparator` in a `TreeMap` using the value as a key, and then insert the sorted result to a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
private LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortByAbsoluteValue(Map<String, Integer> unsorted)
{
    // assemble the comparator function
    Comparator<Integer> sortedByAbsValue = Comparator.comparingInt(Math::abs);
    Comparator<Integer> sortedByAbsValueReversed = sortedByAbsValue.reversed();

    // group by value, sorting using the custom comparator
    TreeMap<Integer, List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>> sorted = new TreeMap<>(sortedByAbsValueReversed);
    sorted.putAll(unsorted.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue)));

    // assemble back into a map that maintains insertion order
    return sorted.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(kv -> kv.getValue().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> b, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```